motivation behind using PQCs in QML and Variational Algorithms
Parameterized quantum circuits (PQCs) are a key component in many quantum machine learning (QML) and variational quantum algorithms, such as the Variational Quantum Eigensolver (VQE) and quantum neural networks.
I have heard that PQCs can be viewed as highly expressive machine learning models, with the ability to represent a wide range of functions. And this stems from the exponential size of the Hilbert space, which allows PQCs to potentially capture complex patterns in data more efficiently than classical models. Could someone give references for such statements?
I know that there are no provable advantages(w.r.t the classical counterparts) to using PQCs in NISQ era. But what exactly is the thinking behind what could be the possible advantage? Looking for mathematical reasons for the same.

I suspect there's more going on than this but VQE is a classical optimizing algorithm combined with a cost function which is implemented on a quantum circuit. In order to have any hope of beating the classical version, this cost function shouldn't be able to be simulated classically. The next line of reasoning is 'Quantum circuits are easy to run on quantum computers but hard to simulate classically' and then we make sure the PQC is universal so should be hard to evaluate. Why any of this is helpful to problem we are trying to do VQE on is more unclear...
